# How do I share a function that uses "Response" or "Request" in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, request, httprequest, httpresponse

I'd like to have a utility function that conditionally updates my request and response across several pages in my site.

Using a standard .CS class doesn't seem to give me access to these objects.  How can I (generall speaking) create a utility function that checks for a cookie and update it across multiple pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get at these things via

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response
```

[HttpContext Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) and the [Current Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx)

> Encapsulates all HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP request.

---

And to manage some cookie value throughout your site I would suggest either create a BasePage class that all of your Pages inherited from and do the checks there:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateCookie();
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

do the same in your MasterPage:

```
public class SiteMasterPage : MasterPage
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateCookie();
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

---

```
public static void UpdateCookie()
{
    HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    HttpCookie cookie = context.Response.Cookies.Get("Update") 
        ?? new HttpCookie("Update");        

    int value = 0;
    int.TryParse(cookie.Value, out value);
    value++;

    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    cookie.Value = value.ToString();
    context.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the equivalant of onPreRender for WCF services?  Some Javascript will be calling some services and I will validate the cookie contents prior to each call.

Answer (score 1):

use HttpContext.Current.Request and HttpContext.Current.Response

Answer (score 0):

Use the fully qualified namespace:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response
```

-- or --

```
using System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
```

Then you should be able to access Request/Response throughout your class.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. Other have mentioned doing this with `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`, but I'd think (guessing from what I think your intent is) that doing this on a method that runs on load on your master pages is a better idea.